# edit_post_link returns blank

Tags: template-tags, quick-edit

I'm using edit_post_link in The Loop and the function keeps returning the $before and $after arguments with blank content.

```
<?php edit_post_link('edit', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
```

returns

```
<p></p>
```

And the weird part is, it was working fine a couple of days ago.

Comment: Are you logged it? Do you have the relevant permissions to edit the post you are viewing? If yes to both of those, please edit your question to include your code for the template in question - unfortunately it's impossible to help without it.

Comment: I'm logged in and the permissions are correct. This is happening for all users even admins. As for the rest of the code it is the regular Loop in single.php. Rest of the Loop seem to work fine.

Comment: I say again - Please edit your question to include your code for the template in question - unfortunately it's impossible to help without it.